# Hot reloading old Ant-based Java webapp

Tags: java, ant, eclipse-wtp, hotdeploy

I have a web app that runs on Ant and I use Tomcat or JBoss to test it locally in Eclipse (but I can use something else).  Are there any good ways for me to hot re-load my application? I'm hoping to do this so that I can reload classes and not need to log into the app again.

I would also be interested in ways to redeploy while that would allow me to keep my session.

I hope to do this without changing my build around too much.  I can't afford JRebel and my employer wouldn't be will to pay for anything.

Answer (score 0):

What ide are you using? For example Jetbrains IDEA perfectly supports hot redeploy. When you deploy your webapp configure it as exploded. Once you start the debug session, if you change a class file, under the Run menu select Reload Changed Classes. New class code should be deployed.

Comment: I am using Eclipse.  I edited my question to reflect that.  Thank you.